# Block blob service: timeout on exists doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.baseblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#exists-container-name--blob-name-none--snapshot-none--timeout-none-), one can set `timeout` on `exists` call to check if a container exists in Azure storage with timeout. One would think that the call returns `False` if either the container does not exist, or the time has elapsed. However, I don't see the timeout taking any effect. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The way `exists` method works is that it makes a `HEAD` request to the resource.

If the request is successful, it returns true.

If the request fails for any reason, exception type is checked. Only in case of `Not Found` exception (HTTP Status Code 404), false is returned.

Any other errors are thrown back to the caller. So in your case if timeout has elapsed, you should expect a timeout exception and must be prepared to handle that exception.

Comment: No exception was thrown. Set timeout of 5 (seconds). The response came back as true, 3 minutes later! Using python SDK. Command used: `block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text(container_name, blob_name, timeout=5)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the timeout is an input argument. "The timeout parameter is expressed in seconds". If you put a very small number in timeout, and you have a bad network, you will probably received the timeout exception. This is probably to prevent endless trying on this calling, which blocks the whole process. Would you like to have a try?